# Cross-ratio for projective lines over division rings

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, projective-geometry, division-rings

If one considers a projective line over a field $k$, then the cross-ratio $(w,x;y,z)$ is a well-known geometric tool.

But what if $k$ is not commutative, that is, if $k$ is a division ring ?

Is there a natural definition in this case ? And if so, which properties does it share with the "commutative cross-ratio" ?

Comment: One can define the cross-ratio as a conjugacy class in the multiplicative group $k^*$ — if $k$ is commutative you get back the usual cross-ratio. This is explained for instance in Bourbaki's *Algebra*, ch. 2, §9, exerc. 11 (note that for Bourbaki a field is not necessarily commutative).